# Is it possible to develop windows phone 8/8.1 app on vista?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

My old Dell laptop os is vista.
Just wonder if it is possible to develop windows phone 8/8.1 app on vista?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be impossible. I've tried to develop win phone 8 on Win7, Visual Studio told me that I should update to Win8

Comment: Is Win 8 32-bit OK? If I use physics phone rather than Hyper-V simulator

Comment: @arachide No, you need to have Windows 8, probably because the components for Windows Store simply don't exist pre-Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can't develop because it need minimum windows 8